Problem with outputting flash error messages in Flask
I'm making an application on Flask, it has forms in it:
class AddArticleForm(FlaskForm):
    """The class defines the form for adding news."""

    name_article: str = StringField('Title of the article',
                                    validators=[DataRequired()])
    text_article: str = TextAreaField('Text of the article',
                                      validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_photo: str = FileField('Upload photo')
    submit = SubmitField('Add an article')


class AddItemForm(FlaskForm):
    """The class defines the form for adding products."""

    name: str = StringField('Product Name',
                            validators=[DataRequired(),
                                        Length(min=3, max=15)])
    description: str = TextAreaField('Product Description',
                                     validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                 Length(min=3)])
    price: int = FloatField('Price', validators=[DataRequired(),
                                                NumberRange(min=0)])
    category: int = SelectField('Category',
                                choices=[('1', 'Category 1'),
                                         ('2', 'Category 2'),
                                         ('3', 'Category 3'),
                                         ('4', 'Category 4'),
                                         ('5', 'Category 5'),
                                         ('6', 'Category 6'),
                                         ('7', 'Category 7'),
                                         ('8', 'Category 8')],
                                coerce=int,
                                validators=[DataRequired()])
    photo: str = FileField('Product photo')
    submit = SubmitField('Add item')

Then there are classes that allow input values (int/str) to be validated:
class CheckingValue:
    """Base class for various input value checks."""

    def __init__(self, value: object):
        """
        Initializes an object of the class CheckingValue.

        :param value: Input value.
        """
        self.value = value


class CheckingText(CheckingValue):
    """A class for various string value checks."""

    def check_length(self, min_length: int, max_length: int) -> bool:
        """
        Checks the length of the value within the specified range.

        :param min_length: Minimum value length.
        :param max_length: Maximum value length.

        Returns:
            bool: Inspection result.
        """
        if not isinstance(self.value, str):
            logger.error("TypeError %s", "check_length")
            return False
        return (min_length <= len(self.value) <= max_length)

    def check_latin(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the value contains only characters of the Latin alphabet.

        Returns:
            bool: Inspection result.
        """
        if not isinstance(self.value, str):
            logger.error("TypeError %s", "check_check_latin")
            return False
        return not all(c.isalpha() and c.isascii() for c in self.value)


class CheckingNumber(CheckingValue):
    """A class for various checks of numeric values."""

    def check_category(self) -> bool:
        """
        Checks the value against one of the categories.

        Returns:
            bool: Inspection result.
        """
        return int(self.value) in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

There is CSS code for 2 pages(error view/successful add view):
.flash.success_panel {
        top: -45px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 3%;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
        color: green;
        font-size: 11px;
        width: 370px;
    }

    .flash.error_panel {
        top: -45px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 3%;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
        color: red;
        font-size: 11px;
        width: 370px;
    }

.flash.success_article {
        top: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
        color: green;
        font-size: 19px;
        width: 600px;
    }

    .flash.error_article {
        top: 0px;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 2%;
        position: relative;
        font-family: 'Days One', sans-serif;
        color: red;
        font-size: 19px;
        width: 600px;
    }

There are also handlers, first:
class AdminArcticel(WorkingWithHandlers):
    """
    A class for processing the form for adding news to the database.

    Returns:
        After passing all checks, adds the news to the database.
    """

    decorators = [login_required]

    def __init__(self, name_page):
        """
        Initializes an object of the class AdminArcticel.

        :param name_page: Title of the page for adding articles
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.name_page = name_page

    def dispatch_request(self):
        """
        Realizes the addition of a news item to the database.

        Method:
        1. Checks the request method and validation of the form.
        2. Gets the data from the form validates it and checks for a photo name.
        3. Saves the photo to the uploads folder and saves the aitem to the database.
        4. Outputs a message that the addition was successful, otherwise, outputs an error        message at each step.
        """
        app.logger.info('Incoming request: %s %s', request.method, request.path)
        form = AddArticleForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                name = request.form['name_article']
                text = request.form['text_article']
                photo = request.files['add_photo']

                utc_timezone = pytz.utc
                utc_time = datetime.now(utc_timezone)
                eet_time = utc_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('EET'))

                if photo:
                    filename = secure_filename(photo.filename)
                    photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                            filename))
                else:
                    filename = None

                name_length = CheckingText(name)
                name_latin = CheckingText(name)
                text_latin = CheckingText(text)
                text_length = CheckingText(text)

                error_messages = []

                if not name_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                                max_length=100):
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[1])
                if not name_latin.check_latin():
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[3])
                if not text_latin.check_latin():
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[4])
                if not text_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                                max_length=1000):
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[2])
                if filename is None:
                    error_messages.append(cont_info[2])

                if error_messages:
                    for error_msg in error_messages:
                        flash(error_msg, category='error_article')
                    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))

                try:
                    new_article = Article(name=name,
                                          text=text,
                                          photo=filename,
                                          pub_date=eet_time)
                    db.session.add(new_article)
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash(cont_info[1], category='success_article')
                    logger.info(f"{cont_info[1]} |AddArticleForm|")
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.error("Exception %s %s",
                                 f"{cont_error[8]}|AddArticleForm|",
                                 ex)
                return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
        return render_template(f'admin/{self.name_page}.html',
                               check_total=check_auth(), form=form)

And so does the second handler:
class AdminPanel(WorkingWithHandlers):
    """
    A class for processing the form for adding a product to the database.

    Returns:
        After passing all checks, adds the aitem to the database.
    """

    decorators = [login_required]

    def __init__(self, name_page: str):
        """
        Initializes an object of the class AdminPanel.

        :param name_page: Admin panel page title.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.name_page = name_page

    def dispatch_request(self):
        """
        Realizes the addition of an aitem to the database.

        Method:
        1. Checks the request method and validation of the form.
        2. Gets the data from the form validates it and checks for a photo name.
        3. Saves the photo to the uploads folder and saves the aitem to the database.
        4. Outputs a message that the addition was successful, otherwise, outputs an error message at each step.
        """
        app.logger.info('Incoming request: %s %s',
                        request.method, request.path)
        form = AddItemForm()

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                name = request.form['name']
                description = request.form['description']
                price = request.form['price']
                category = request.form['category']
                photo = request.files['photo']

                if photo:
                    filename = secure_filename(photo.filename)
                    photo.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                                            filename))
                else:
                    filename = None

                name_length = CheckingText(name)
                description_length = CheckingText(description)
                name_latin = CheckingText(name)
                description_latin = CheckingText(description)
                check_category = CheckingNumber(category)

                error_messages = []

                if not name_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                                max_length=15):
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[5])
                if not description_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                                       max_length=350):
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[2])
                if not name_latin.check_latin():
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[3])
                if not description_latin.check_latin():
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[4])
                if not check_category.check_category():
                    error_messages.append(cont_error[6])
                if filename is None:
                    error_messages.append(cont_info[2])

                if error_messages:
                    for error_msg in error_messages:
                        flash(error_msg, category='error_panel')
                    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))

                try:
                    new_item = Item(name=name,
                                    description=description,
                                    price=price,
                                    category=category,
                                    photo=filename)
                    db.session.add(new_item)
                    db.session.commit()
                    flash(cont_info[1], category='success_panel')
                    logger.info(f"{cont_info[1]} |AddItemForm|")
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.info("Exception %s %s",
                                f"{cont_error[8]}|AddItemForm|",
                                ex)
                return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
        return render_template(f'admin/{self.name_page}.html',
                               check_total=check_auth(), form=form)

Суть проблемы: у класса AdminArcticel при допущении ошибок в заполнении формы, появляются flash() сообщения на странице, а если все проверки пройдены, то сообщение об удачном добавлении айтема в базу данных, а у класса AdminPanel, появляются только сообщения об успешном добавлении, а ошибки нет. Сущности "cont_info" и "cont_error" это словари со строками (конкретным текстом ошибок по типу: "Название должно состоять из 3-х - 15-ти символов...").
I tried to connect logging, it shows that when errors are made in AdminPanel, form validation does not pass, but in AdminArticcle everything passes in any case (both with errors and with successful addition).
p.s.:
I also want to add that if I do this kind of check, then for some reason one error appears on the page, but through the list(several) - no.
if not name_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                max_length=15):
    flash(cont_error[5], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
if not name_latin.check_latin():
    flash(cont_error[3], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
if not description_length.check_length(min_length=3,
                                       max_length=350):
    flash(cont_error[2], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
if not description_latin.check_latin():
    flash(cont_error[4], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
if not check_category.check_category():
    flash(cont_error[6], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))
if filename is None:
    flash(cont_info[2], category='error_panel')
    return redirect(url_for(self.name_page))

